# Django: How to save new email address after sending verification email

Tags: django, email

I'm creating the logic a new email address is verified with confirmation email.
But I don't get how I can save the new email address after sending the verification email. I need to save the new email address somewhere so I can save it when the user checked the verification email.
How does the verification logic usually work?

My current code is like this

`views.py`

```
def change_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangeEmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # send the verification email here while creating a token
            ...
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('new_email')
            email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[to_email],)
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect...


def verify_email(request, uid64, token):
    # user verify the new email address when checking the verification email here but how I can save the new email address the user input
```

How I can save the new email address the user input or save the new email address value on the form so I can save it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the User model to add an additional field "new_email" and then save it before you send the email.

```
def change_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = ChangeEmailForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            request.user.new_email = form.cleaned_data['new_email']
            request.user.save()
            ...
```